# Must the SPICE M= multiply parameter be an integer?

Tags: spice

M= is used as a multiplier of component values in SPICE to effectively create multiple parallel copies of SPICE components.  I think of it as a current-controlled current source on every pin of a device.

Does the M value have to be an integer?

Comment: Do you think the answer is the same for every SPICE? How long would it take you to try it and find out for your SPICE?

Comment: @ThePhoton - Google and stackexchange do not suggest any answers to your first question, which is why, regardless of what I discover in HSPICE and ngspice, it's worth asking and answering here.  A colleague was just asking me if I knew offhand.  The HSPICE documentation suggests only >0 is required.

Comment: @ThePhoton -  do you know the answer for Spectre? For xyspice?

Comment: No, but I don't use those tools so I don't have to. You probably only use one or two SPICEs yourself. So you don't need to know the answer for any but those. Which you could find out in about 30 s by trying it.

Comment: This question basically requires a catalog of all the different SPICEs to answer, and will go out of date when somebody creates a new SPICE, or when any of the existing SPICEs gets a new version. That makes this not a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  it doesn't have to be an integer.

[LTspice: Combining Multiple Model Instances Into One Symbol](http://www.linear.com/solutions/6085)

> A number of intrinsic devices support the M (parallel units)
>   parameter, such as the capacitor, inductor, diode and MOSFET models.
>   If you are not sure if the model supports the M (parallel units)
>   parameter, try it, and if you do not get an error message, you should
>   be good. The diode (including LED) model is the only intrinsic model
>   that supports N (series units) parameter.
>
> To define multiple instances of a model in a device symbol: Ctrl + right-click the symbol to edit the component attributes.
>   Insert “m=” or “n=” into the Value2 field.
>
> Note that **non-integer  values are allowed**.

Comment: Re-reading this years later, I'm intrigued that `m` is described as a model feature and not a simulator or language feature here.